# Selenium doesn't load redirect page

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, redirect, selenium-chromedriver

I have a tool which load a website, fill in the information, and save the result. 
It was working fine until last week.
After debugging, I found out the reason is because the site URL "became" redirected.

The redirected sequence is like below. (for example, site url is `google.com`)

google.com` → google.com\somethingbetween → google.com (yes, the final redirected url is exactly the same as the original url)

If I open chrome and navigate to the url manually, the page is loaded fine. But if opened by selenium chromedriver, it will stop as `google.com\somethingbetween`. The strange thing is if I manually enter the url inside the address bar of the browser which was opened by ChromeDirver (will have a little popup saying that the browser is currently controlled by automation tool), the browser will also stop at the second page ( `google.com\somethingbetween`).

I tried to use the Chrome beta version 79 (with chrome driver v79) but the problem didn't go away.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trails and the trace logs?

Answer (score 3):

Use Chrome driver of stable version which may help you to get rid of this problem.Because under this version there is an issue of "**issue 3133: window.navigator.webdriver is undefined when "enable-automation" is excluded in non-headless mode (should be true) [Pri-2]**.So do try with the stable versions like v78,v77.

Comment: Good information +1 However I see the fix being available in _ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.16 (2019-10-30)_ As OP is using **chrome driver v79** this shouldn't have been any issue.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium  - I am facing the same issue with Chrome browser 116 and I think Chrome driver 79 will not support Chrome 116 so is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The redirection issue occurs when "driver.get()" method is used. Please try using "driver.navigate().to()" method to navigate to the url. This may solve the issue.

Linking a related question:
[How do I switch to redirected url using selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755839/how-do-i-switch-to-redirected-url-using-selenium-web-driver)