# Webpage does not load in python selenium with Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I try to crawl [rugdoc.io](https://rugdoc.io/). When I do so manually, I first see a page which says *Checking your browser. Just wait a moment.* Then, after a second or so, the actual content gets displayed.
When I do so with `selenium`, I always stay on the *wait a moment* page.
How can it work manually but not with `selenium`? How can [rugdoc.io](https://rugdoc.io/) know that the webpage is accessed automatically? Does `selenium` open `Chrome` with some extra options?
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/lukas.denk/Downloads/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://rugdoc.io/")
time.sleep(10)

#still the "just wait a moment" webpage
loaded_webpage_should_be_here=driver.page_source
```

`Chrome` version: `100.0.4896.127 (arm64)`.
`ChromeDriver` version: `100.0.4896.60`.
MacOs: `12.3.1` - with `M1 Max`.
`selenium` version: `4.1.3`.
`Python` version: `3.8`

**EDIT:** It may have sth to do that `selenium` has problems with webpages that are redirecting to another webpage (see e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066071/selenium-doesnt-load-redirect-page)). When I visit [rugdoc.io](https://rugdoc.io/), it seems to redirect me to https://rugdoc.io/?__cf_chl_tk=hkaULMeBxwgnTv0SgwmOY62fuDatlRLnupbDymXWWs0-1650454179-0-gaNycGzNBpE and then back to [rugdoc.io](https://rugdoc.io/).
However, the solution in the [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066071/selenium-doesnt-load-redirect-page) proposes to use a `driver.navigate().to()` function which does not exist in the `python` `selenium`.

Answer (score 1):

Had to run your code to understand your problem :(

The issue you are running into is the DDoS CloudFare protection that won't allow for webdriver requests to go through to protect the site against automatic requests and DDoS :)

You can check this webdriver alternative that doesn't have those restrictions:
https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

Comment: But do you know how it detects that I am crawling with webdriver? Since webdriver just opens the webpage once, there is no reason for the webdriver to behave differently from a real person. At least in theory.

Comment: There are several ways that this detection occurs. Check this blog post for some examples and how to (manually) bypass them: https://piprogramming.org/articles/How-to-make-Selenium-undetectable-and-stealth--7-Ways-to-hide-your-Bot-Automation-from-Detection-0000000017.html